# String interpolation in Scala?

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I wanted to ask if there is any type of string interpolation in Scala. I have made a search on the subject but 'till now I have found that there is no string interpolation. Is there plans to get implemented in next versions?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

String interpolation is going to be in scala 2.10 which you can try out since scala 2.10.RC1 is out (20/10/2012). You can check out this [SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/string-interpolation.html) for scala 2.11 which states that interpolated strings in the pattern matcher will be valid syntax. With the new string interpolation you can do something like this:

```
val age = 28
val name = "Gerry"

s"My name is $name and I am $age years old"
res0: String = My name is Gerry and I am 28 years old
```

But try out the [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) on all the interpolators that are available at the moment. Note that you can define your own interpolators! Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404399/indentation-preserving-string-interpolation-in-scala) for more info.

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/index.html

Comment: For completeness, the argument for not having those was that `"("+value+")"` was only one character longer than `"(#{value})"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there no string interpolation in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481459/why-is-there-no-string-interpolation-in-scala)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not in the (released) scala library yet. But there is a SIP (Scala Improvement Process) for the addition of this feature:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/string-interpolation.html

Comment: It's also already in trunk (as experimental feature): https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/25812/

Comment: @tenshi thanks! I was going to check if trunk had this, if I'd had time.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it C-style:

```
"Interpolate my %s here" format List(1,2,3)

//String = Interpolate my List(1, 2, 3) here
```

or

```
List(1,2,3) formatted "Interpolate my %s here"
```

You can use these on anything with a toString (i.e. anything)

```
case class Foo(n: Int)
Foo(42) formatted "Here is a %s !!!!"
//String = Here is a Foo(42) !!!!
```

although the former is more flexible in terms of enabling multiple interpolations in a single string (since it can take multiple arguments).

Answer (score 7):

I use the xml hack on scala 2.9

```
val age = 28
val name = "Gerry"

<a>My name is {name} and I am {age} years old</a>.text
res0: String = My name is Gerry and I am 28 years old
```

Comment: This may be old, but it's a nice hack!

Comment: How might you do this with a run time string instead of `<a>` wrapped one you have inline?

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is string interpolation in current scala releases via compiler plugin
see http://jrudolph.github.com/scala-enhanced-strings

Answer (score 0):

This days (Dec. 2016, Scala 2.12, five years later), you can write your own string interpolation.
See [**`co.ntextu.al`**](http://co.ntextu.al/)

> Contextual is a small Scala library which allows you to define your own string interpolators—prefixed string literals like `uri"https://google.com"` which determine how they should be evaluated, at runtime and at compile-time, while only writing very ordinary user code: no macros!

For instance, [`contextual/examples/email.scala`](https://github.com/propensive/contextual/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/contextual/examples/email.scala) allows to [check at compile time the validity of an email address](http://co.ntextu.al/email).

```
import contextual.examples.email._
email"""info@scala.world"""

import contextual.examples.email._
email"""john.smith@hotmail.com"""
```