# Import Class: error: not found: object Controller

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner in scala, without java background. I don't understand the import system.
I have my application, where i use the import

```
import Array._
import List._
import Controller.api
object scalaStart{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
            var apiCtrl = new api()
            apiCtrl.getById(1)
            println(apiCtrl.title)
    }

}
```

And this is the class:

```
package Controller
 class api {
  var id:Int
  var title:String
  var description:String
  def getById(id:Int){
    if(id = 1){
      this.id           = 1
      this.title        = s"Title Nummer ${this.id}"
      this.description  = s"Description Nummer ${this.id}" 
    }else{
      this.id           = 1
      this.title        = s"Artikel mit der ID: ${this.id} existiert nicht."
      this.description  = s"Kein Eintrag mit der ID: ${this.id}" 
    }
  }
}
```

i checked also only import api and import controller and wildcards controller._ controller.api._.

Comment: What's your directory layout? Are you using sbt?

Comment: No, i don't using sbt. GettingStart/src/controller/api.scala and GettingStart/src/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.scala. It's automaticly build with Netbeans and the scala Plugin.

Comment: Upper/lower case can matter in package names on case-sensitive file systems. Idiom is that packages are lower case, classes started with Upper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Philipp, your code actually does not compile.
In the line `if(id=1){` it should be `if(id==1)`.
Try to correct this and rebuild your project.
You will notice that compiler will give you another error:

> Error:(5, 7) class api needs to be abstract, since: it has 3
>   unimplemented members. /** As seen from class api, the missing
>   signatures are as follows.  *  For convenience, these are usable as
>   stub implementations.  */   def description_=(x$1: String): Unit = ???
>   def id_=(x$1: Int): Unit = ???   def title_=(x$1: String): Unit = ???
>   class api {
>         ^

This is because in Scala you can't leave variable declarations abstract as you could do in Java. Instead of `var id:Int` you need to put something liek `var id:Int = 0` and the same for other declared variables.

Comment: Thanks. Big stupid failure. I initialized also the Strings:  `var id:Int = 0
  var title:String = ""
  var description:String = "" `Then i compiled the controller package and it works. But i can't use String Interpolation like this: `this.title  = s"Title Nummer {this.id}" `

Comment: You are welcome.
For me, after I fixed all these problems it gives me following when I run:
`Title Nummer 1`
Is it the same for you?

Comment: I got error: ';' expected but string literal found.
      this.title        = s"Title Nummer ${this.id}"  I have Scala Version 2.9

Comment: No. I checked it without the s. I got this result: Title Nummer ${this.id}
 Need i import something for interpolation?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917462/string-interpolation-in-scala Seems like string interpolation introduced in Scala 2.10. So upgrade and you will be lucky :)

Comment: I have to read the doc: Starting in Scala 2.10.0, ... tanks :D